# Admob Ads not showing when i create a release Version in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-play, admob

I have an App on Google play, all is fine, I have created a new app to replace it, an upgrade, I have got Admob currently running on the existing App. So when i created the new app, all works fine in Debug release, even with my AD ID's, it shows my Ads and reflects in the reports in Admob.

When i create a release version though, no ads show. I have looked around and some people say it may have an issue with proguard-rules, and have tried all different things but cannot get it working.

These are my current files

build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystorePropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        keystoreProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.buzzr.psl"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 43
        versionName "6.0.1"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }


    googleServices { disableVersionCheck = true }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}
```

proguard_rules.pro

```
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.ads.** { *; }
```

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.iqonic.news_flutter">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Match Report">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.onesignal.suppressLaunchURLs"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-4903778266431401~7023645874" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Not sure what else would help to solve this, but i have tried lots and looked all over for a solution.

Its not a matter of waiting for ads to be approved as Admob has been running on my package for years already.

Any help would be appriciated.

Tried adding
proguard-rules.pro

Tried
shrinkResources true
minifyEnabled true

and

shrinkResources false
minifyEnabled false

Comment: Have you added the permissions in android manifest?

Comment: Just added the manifest file above, think its all in. Like i said all works 100% with the Debug Version, but Release nothing shows, so think its somway its building that changing

Answer (score 0):

Inside `build.gradle` include the first implementation below

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}
```